Why am I unable to remove failed disk from Windows Storage Pool (set as mirror)?
I have a Windows Storage Pool configured as a mirror, and one day, one of the disks failed unexpectedly — there were no warnings, it just disappeared from the system.
I purchased a replacement disk and installed it, but the failed disk is still showing in the pool. It seems that I need to add a new disk to the pool before I can remove the failed one, which doesn’t make much sense to me, but I understand that it’s how the system works.
Here’s the issue: I’ve installed the new disk, but I’m unable to remove the failed disk from the pool in order to add the new one and repair the storage pool. specifically, i get the same message every time “before this disk can be removed, a new one of the same size must first be added to the pool”.
I still get this message from before, even though there are now 3 disks in the pool.
To work with PowerShell is not getting any easier, because the “friendly name” is of course exactly the same as the new disk.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

Update: After some troubleshooting, I resolved it by completely resetting the new disk using diskpart:

Open a command prompt with admin rights.
Enter diskpart and run the following commands:
list disk
select disk <disk number>
clean all



After resetting the disk, I was able to add it to the pool and enter repair mode. Now, I'm waiting for the repair process to reach 100%, after which I plan to remove the faulty disk from the pool.
It is now at 100%, but I still can't remove the faulty disk from the pool. When I now go back to repair mode, it immediately jumps to 100%. But the pool still has this warning sign and I still can't remove the faulty disk from the pool.

You shouldn’t be limited to just X number of disks, even in mirror mode, you should be able to add another disks to exceed the minimum number of disks and then remove the old disk once the rebuild is complete

i could not add a new disk to the pool (option was grayed out)
but i have now completely reset the new disk (diskpart >clean<)
now I could add it to the pool and go into repair mode.
when it is at 100% i hope to remove the faulty disk from the pool.
i'm finally making progress, i think i'm starting to understand how storage pools works.
